# Is the difference of two decreasing functions also decreasing?

Tags: inequality

If I have two decreasing functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, is their difference
$ H(x)=f(x)-g(x) $ also a decreasing function?

Comment: What's up with the downvotes? I'm not one of the psychic MSE users, so I can't tell why people downvoted (especially since they didn't leave feedback for the OP on how to improve the question).

Comment: This is a genuine question and not a homework question. People should take it easy with the downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, especially if by decreasing you mean "$x > y$ implies $f(x) < f(y)$".

Take $f(x) = -x$ and $g(x) = -x$.  Both are decreasing in the sense I've described above, but $H(x) = 0$ for all $x$.  Then $H(x)$ is not decreasing, since for all $x, y$ with $x > y$, $H(x) = H(y) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Not always. For example $g(x)=-x$ and $f(x)=\frac{-x}{2}+1$

Answer (score 1):

If that were true for differentiable $f,g$ then from $f'(x)<0$ and $g'(x)<0$ would follow $f'(x)-g'(x)<0.$ Can you find an example where this implication doesn't hold?

Answer (score 0):

False by counterexample:

$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^3}$, and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ on $[1,\infty)$